# "being to talk to" structure?

Tags: being

The Q is: For them, the task was identified as *being to talk to* important (or knowledgeable) people and elicit information...

Can you explain me how does it mean and what is the structure for that part?

Comment: Identified as being:  To talk ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying structure is

> The task was "to talk to important people..."

so the name or description of the task is that to-infinitive clause.

That is embedded in the structure

> X was identified as being Y.

So, putting them together

> The task was identified as being "to talk to ..."

(They didn't use quotation marks, but I think the sentence is unclear without them).